# Fast computation of real eigenvalues of special $4\times 4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For distance calculations between ellipses$^1$, I have to find the real eigenvalues of a lot of $4\times 4$ matrices that have the shape

$$\left[ \begin{matrix} -2a & b & 2a & a^2 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0&0&1&0 \end{matrix}\right]\tag{1}$$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and characteristic polynomial
$$\lambda^4+2a\lambda^3-b\lambda^2-2a\lambda-a^2=0.\tag{2}$$ In the given situation we have $a\approx -10^7$ and $b\approx-10^{14}$. This leads to the observation that the $4$ eigenvalues are always a pair of complex conjugated eigenvalues $\rho = q \pm ir$ and a pair of real eigenvalues $\pm m$. Both pairs are not mathematically identical but identical up to floating point precision that is sufficient for this case.

There is some redundancy as the complex solutions are not needed and the real solutions can be considered identical (except of sign) for practical reasons.

Does this redundancy allow for faster solving of the polynomial to get |m|?

*Example*

$a=-10^7, b=-3\times 10^{14}$

Eigenvalues (identical only up to floating point precision): $\pm 0.57735, (1\pm i1.41421)10^7 $

Of interest for fast calculation would be only $|m|=0.57735$.

*Solution*

In the comments the solution
$m\approx |a|/\sqrt{-b}$ was given that seems acceptable for the given number range.

---

$^1$ Ik-Sung Kim: An algorithm for finding the distance between two ellipses, Commun. Korean Math. Soc.  21, 559 (2006).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion that there are two eigenvalues $\rho = q + ir$ and $\rho^*$ and two $\pm m$ implies that $a$ and $b$ are not separately free parameters. It is equivalent to stating that the characteristic polynomial factorizes as
$$
\lambda^4 + 2a\lambda^3 - b \lambda^2 - 2a \lambda - a^2 = (\lambda^2 - m^2) (\lambda^2 -2q \lambda + \left| \rho \right|^2) = \lambda^4 - 2 q \lambda^3 + \left( \left| \rho \right|^2 - m^2 \right) \lambda^2 + 2qm^2 \lambda - m^2 \left| \rho \right|^2 
$$
Matching coefficients, we have
$$
2a = -2q \\
-b = \left| \rho \right|^2 - m^2 \\
-2a = 2qm^2 \\
-a^2 = - m^2 \left| \rho \right|^2
$$
This has the the solutions $q = -a$ and $m = 1$, from the first and third equations (the sign of $m$ is arbitrary). So, $\rho = -a + ir$ and $\left| \rho \right|^2 = a^2 + r^2$. Then the second and fourth equations become
$$
-b = a^2 + r^2 - 1 \\
-a^2 = -\left| \rho \right|^2 = -a^2-r^2
$$
The latter requires that $r=0$, and therefore the former requires that
$$
b = 1-a^2.
$$
The eigenvalues are, in summary, $\pm 1$ and a double-valued real solution $-a$.

---

If the two real solutions are not exactly equal, that makes things much harder. Let the roots be $\pm m - \delta$:

$$
\lambda^4 + 2a\lambda^3 - b \lambda^2 - 2a \lambda - a^2 = \left(\lambda -m +\delta \right) \left( \lambda + m + \delta \right) (\lambda^2 -2q \lambda + \left| \rho \right|^2) \\
= \lambda^4 -2(q+\delta) \lambda^3 + \left( \left| \rho \right|^2 + 4 \delta q - m^2 + \delta^2 \right) \lambda^2 + 2(qm^2-q\delta^2-\delta \left| \rho \right|^2 ) \lambda - (m^2-\delta)^2 \left| \rho \right|^2 
$$
Matching terms again gives
$$
a = -q - \delta \\
-b = \left| \rho \right|^2 + 4 \delta q - m^2 + \delta^2 \\
-a = qm^2-q\delta^2-\delta \left| \rho \right|^2 \\
a^2 = (m^2-\delta)^2 \left| \rho \right|^2 
$$
The first equation can be used to eliminate $q$, equal to $-a-\delta$, yielding
$$
-b = (a+\delta)^2 + r^2 - 4 \delta (a+\delta) - m^2 + \delta^2
$$
$$
a = (a+\delta)(m^2-\delta^2)+\delta \left( (a+\delta)^2 + r^2 \right) $$
$$
a^2 = (m^2-\delta)^2 \left( (a+\delta)^2 + r^2 \right)
$$
These are three equations for $\delta$, $r$, and $m$. I am not going to proceed further, but with some effort, it might be possible to eliminate variables and solve for $\delta$. Note that currently they are no simpler than the original (the fourth in particular is quartic in $\delta$), but it may also be useful to simply solve this to first order in $\delta$, since it is empirically small.

Comment: Counterexample: $a = -37093425/2, b= -3.4402445 \cdot 10^{14}$, Eigenvalues (rounded): $\pm0.999936,1.85467 \cdot 10^7 \pm 209536 i$

Comment: Sure that's not just floating point error? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Power%5Bx%2C4%5D+-+37093425+Power%5Bx%2C3%5D%2B+%28Divide%5BPower%5B37093425%2C2%5D%2C4%5D-1%29%28Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%29%2B37093425x-Divide%5BPower%5B37093425%2C2%5D%2C4%5D

Comment: For this counter example the real eigenvalues are far from $\pm1$: $a=10^6,b=-10^{13}$, Eigenvalues: $\pm0.3162278560,-10^6 \pm 3\cdot 10^6 i$

Comment: it seems the real eigenvalues are only identical (up to sign) in floating point precision but not in mathematical sense, I included this in the OP.

Comment: I'm not particularly convinced that there aren't small differences in those roots. For one, it looks like you found them with a root finder. For two, if two real numbers rather close to $\pm \sqrt{1/10}$ did solve the polynomial, I think Mathematic/Wolfram would be able to factor the polynomial into quadratics, which it cannot.

Comment: I noticed that in all your examples you always have $b<0$ and huge compared to $a$. Is it the only case you are interested in?

Comment: yes, I added this in the OP.

Comment: @granularbastard In the regime you mentioned, it is just $m\approx |a|/\sqrt{-b}$, but don't abuse this formula beyond its range of applicability :-)